# Let's help out [html-helper]

Tags: discussion, tags

The [html-helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-helper) tag  refers to the `HtmlHelper` class for ASP.NET MVC views. However, recently I noticed that many questions with this tag have nothing to do with ASP.NET, and are usually either

1. Asking people to write code for them and should be closed ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69853289/html-text-color-change-on-click), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69606711/putting-text-over-image-in-html-email-template))
2. Asking for help with their HTML code, and should just have the tag removed ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68058357/can-anybody-help-me-with-login-form-php-with-html), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794294/why-my-media-query-code-is-not-working-in-css))

It looks like about half of the questions on the first page are completely unrelated to ASP.NET MVC views.

What should we do about this? I'm new to the whole Stack Overflow Meta scene but I feel like something should be done.

Comment: There's about [285 mistagged questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=&q=%5Bhtml-helper%5D+-%5Bc%23%5D+is%3Aq+-%5Basp.net*%5D&searchOn=3), and just browsing the front page, the vast majority of them shouldn't have the tag. The rest needs supplemental tags. I'd recommend cleaning up those, then renaming the tag to something else, assuming the tag doesn't meet the criteria for burnination

Comment: There are a handful of tags I've noticed like this which were presumably intended to refer to ASP.NET-specific features, but have pretty generic sounding names, and thus get a lot of cross-contamination from other areas. (In some cases this may be valid—e.g., due to the same name being adopted elsewhere—in other cases it doesn't seem to be.) It strikes me that part of the problem is that these aren't "namespaced" with `asp.net-*` (or, for others, `asp.net-core-*`). That convention is really intermittently maintained.

Comment: So we shouldn't create [`[Quentin]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/html/topusers) as a synonym for `[html-helper]`?

Comment: For the ruby on rails questions, they are probably referring to `FormHelper`, which has a tag `[form-helpers]`.  There's also rails questions with the `[helpers]` tag that probably mean `[form-helpers]`.